# Ubuntu Screen Issues

Tags: server

I have recently installed the 32-bit version of Ubuntu I believe version 16 (For issues that require me to use a 32-bit version of Ubuntu as the most current is only available in 64-bit version). I am attempting to go through the normal setup and installation on Virtualbox, however once I reach the language settings/keyboard settings of the setup, the continue button is off-screen and I do not know how to progress past this point.

If anyone can help me on how to change the screen size so I can continue with my installation. All I need to do is be able to resize the screen so that I may click the continue button and continue on with my Ubuntu installation.

Comment: Did you try System Settings --> Display?

Comment: I wonder why you don't use a current version (e.g. 20.04) It definitely works on the current Virtualbox Version. Why don't you share the following information: Hostsystem, Virtualbox Version... Please edit your question and add that valuable data

Comment: I needed a 32 bit version of the program which is why I don't use version 20.04 as my system is 32 bit. I am using the most recent version of Virtualbox as well, all I am asking is how to make the setup fit my screen so I can simply select on the "continue" option.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you can try Lubuntu or Xubuntu 18.04.04. They both have 32bit versions, and have better support than 16.04.06.

Anyway, the default virtual box resolution is: 800x600 which is why the continue button is cut off.

You can do the following:

- Alt + Right Click to move the window to the left and then continue the install on the default resolution.

OR

- Instead of going to the install menu, click on Try Ubuntu.

  - Either do the following:

    - Go to System Settings menu by clicking on the top right gear icon. Then, go to Displays. Select a higher resolution and click the apply button on the right. (it may be partially covered.) Afterwards, continue the install process.
    - Go to the terminal (shortcut: ctrl+alt+t) and run this command:

      `xrandr --output Virtual1 --mode 1024x768`